# Can't transition on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is for an easy explanation, but for some reason I cant figure out why this is happening. I'm trying to make the greenbox to transition from green to blue color by toggling the changecolor class on click on the redbox. Can anybody point why it is not transitioning? Thanks for the help

```js
document.querySelector('.redbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.greenbox').classList.toggle("changecolor")
})
```

```css
.redbox {
  transition: all 1s ease
}

.greenbox {
  transition: all 1s ease
}

.changecolor {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div style="background:black;height:500px;width:500px;">
  <div class="greenbox" style="background:green;height:50%;width:100%;"></div>
  <div class="redbox" style="background:red;height:20%;width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your inline styling has higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so the class cannot overwrite it. Try moving the inline styling to a CSS class aswell

Comment: Or you could add the `!important` modifier to `.changecolor`, but avoid doing that unless you have to.

Comment: As I thought, the solution had to be simple. Just need to remember when using transitions to use the styling in the style block instead of inline. Thanks for your help.